# Application crashes when using global QNetworkCookieJar for multiple windows

Tags: c++, qt

I am new at Qt and using Qt5.5 to create a http client application which will load a window with a fixed URL. After login in this window the other windows of same site should get the same session. At this purpose I have used global pointer `jar` of `QNetworkCookieJar` class and implemented on the following code for every window

```
Window1::Window1(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Window1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QUrl webURL("http://someURL");
    ui->webView->show();
    ui->webView->load(webURL);

    ui->webView->page()->networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(jar);
}
```

It solves the multiple authentication problem, but when I close any window and reopen it instantly it causes appcrash.

Please give me a suggestion on my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try not calling the `setCookieJar` function and  open and close the windows again see if it still crashes. Chances are your close / open / destroy code is wrong

Comment: without `setCookieJar` function it never crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt5 docs (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setCookieJar):

**Note: QNetworkAccessManager takes ownership of the cookieJar object.**

So the accessmanager will delete your `jar` instance. There might be your problem! I don't know enough about the webview/page/accessmanager to be sure about the lifetime of the manager, but it seems to be bound to the webview/your ui, so when it's closed+destroyed, your cookiejar will have gone, too.

As `QNetworkCookieJar` inherits from QObject, you might want to use a guarded `QPointer<QNetworkCookieJar> jar` instead of a simple `QNetworkCookieJar* jar` variable. Then, you will notice that your guarded pointer becomes null after the first window is closed/destroyed. That would a) verify my claim from the last paragraph and b) guard you against stale pointer accesses in the future (in fact, your program would no longer crash).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **ThorngardSO**..
I have found a solution using your answer. Here is my solution,

```
if(jar.isNull()==true){
    qDebug()<<"object null";
    QPointer <QNetworkCookieJar> jar_new = new QNetworkCookieJar(0);
    ui->webView->page()->networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(jar_new);
    jar=jar_new;
}
else
    ui->webView->page()->networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(jar);
```